# Octave: Convert cell to matrix

Tags: string, octave

I am currently stuck on following: I would like to store the content of cells into a matrix of string ...

I have the following cells:

```
words =     
ans =     
{    
  [1,1] = word1    
}

ans =     
{
      [1,2] = word2    
}
```

and I basically would like to get

```
words =    
word1, word2
```

I am not entirely sure on how to do that ...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use `cell2mat`. See [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Processing-Data-in-Cell-Arrays.html#XREFcell2mat) and [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) docs on it.